# Search Postgres JSON type using greater than/less than

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I am storing hashes in a JSON data type using rails 4 for an api and need to search for values in the hash that meet `<` & `>` conditions.

Using a hash like {location: {"lat": -112, "lng": 33}} for example, I need to be able to find a range of lat and longs.

Something like:

```
Place.where("location ->> "lng" < -111 && > -113)
```

It doesn't appear that Postgres 9.3 supports that though, is there a way in rails around this without using something like:

```
Place.all.select { |place| place.location["lng"] < -111 && > -113 }
```

Comment: what are the attributes in places table?

Comment: The only attribute that is stored in JSON is the location as it is a latitude and longitude

Comment: you are firing query on place table..how?

Comment: `Place.where("location ->> 'lng' < ?", -111)` which I just realized is wrong because you have to search with it based off text right? So "-111" makes it work I believe...

Comment: with which column you are trying to compare 111 and 113? is place belongs_to :location?

Comment: `location` is a column on the `Place` table

Comment: location should be between 111 and 113?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How I was querying for this before was `Place.where("location ->> 'lng' < ?", -111)` which is slightly incorrect

You have to search by text for some reason (I'm sure someone can answer in the comments why this is) so altering the query slightly to `Place.where("location ->> 'lng' < ?", "-111")` seems to work!

Comment: Your new query works because the ->> operator returns data of type `text`. What you want to do is cast this to an integer with `::int`.  I assume the following query would work:
`Place.where("(location->>'lng')::int < ?", -111)`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'll try that tonight when I have a chance to work on this! Thank you so much Miguel!

Comment: If your postgres version >= 9.3 then you can also use: `Place.where("(location ->> 'lng')::numeric < ?", -111)`. This can be useful if your value has a float type.